# redirect php script with .htaccess from upper folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to do a 301 redirect with mod_rewrite on a PHP script from an upper directory on my website. The URL I want to redirect looks like this (obviously the querystring is always different).

```
http://www.foo.com/bar/script.php?variable1=bar&variable2=foo
```

And I want to redirect script.php? to the lower lever on my site, like this:

```
http://www.foo.com/script.php?variable1=bar&variaable2=foo
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vhost config (which i prefer to a htaccess), it would be

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bar/script.php
  RewriteRule $ /index.php [R=301,NC]
```

for htaccess it should be

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bar/script.php
  RewriteRule $ /index.php [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: This is not a 301 redirect. It's not even a redirect.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer, worked a charm :) The only change needed was on the bottom line, I changed this too 'RewriteRule $ /script.php [R=301,NC]' Cheers, Matt

Comment: @matt, you're welcome, hm, yeah it was script.php not index.php Oops :D well you got the idea

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bar/script\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/script.php [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: For the records: I've just tested it and it works for me :-? Never mind, I'm glad you got it anyway.